# Use C++11 In JNI cannot find jni.h

Tags: c++11, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin

I used Android Studio 1.5.1 and android-ndk-r10e
Before I write some C++11 code and try to compile some C++11 code using android-ndk-r10e, the application is working well.

```
#include <jni.h>
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication60_MainActivity_getStringFromNative
        (JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

After I Add -std=c++11 into app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication60"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
            ndk{
                moduleName "libJniTest"
                ldLibs "log"
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
                cFlags  "-std=c++11"
                stl "gnustl_static"
            }
}
sourceSets{
    main{
        jniLibs.srcDirs=[]
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}...
```

Then, the IDE tell me it cannot find jni.h

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem....

It is a bug in Androind Studio 2.0 Preview.

Ref: [Issue 195483](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195483): Android Studio cannot find jni.h, but compilation still works.

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []
```

set it to module `build.gradle`, it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

try to add to your gradle.build. bad way, but it works.

`module {
   android.ndk {
     cppFlags.add("-I" + file("<path-to-your-ndk>/platforms/android-19/arch-mips/usr/include").absolutePath)
    }
}`